# Kotlin Dagger Module not set

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

New to kotlin and trying to migrate over a small Android project written in Java. Don't know what to make of this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   com.mydomain.example.dagger.BusModule must be set
>   
> >         at com.mydomain.example.dagger.DaggerAppComponent$Builder.build(DaggerAppComponent.java:87)
>   
> >         at com.mydomain.example.MyApplication.buildComponent(MyApplication.kt:29)
>   
> >         at com.mydomain.example.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.kt:17)
>   
> >         at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>   
> >         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5791)

Here is the `BusModule` class:

```
@Module
object BusModule {

    const val PROVIDER_FRAGMENT_SELECTION = "fragment_selection"

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(PROVIDER_FRAGMENT_SELECTION)
    fun provideNewFragmentSelection(): PublishSubject<String> {
        return PublishSubject.create()
    }
}
```

And here is the AppComponent class:

```
@Component(modules = [(AppModule::class), (DataModule::class), (BusModule::class)])
@Singleton
interface AppComponent {

    @get:Named(BusModule.PROVIDER_FRAGMENT_SELECTION)
    val selectedFragmentName: PublishSubject<String>

    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)
}
```

And finally, the application class:

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appComponent = buildComponent()
    }

    private fun buildComponent(): AppComponent {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().build()
    }

    companion object {

        var appComponent: AppComponent? = null
            private set
    }
}
```

Can't figure out what the error message means. How is the BusModule not 'set'? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BusModule` should be a class instead of an object and `const val PROVIDER_FRAGMENT_SELECTION` should be moved to `companion object` of the class. So the module becomes:

```
@Module
class BusModule {
    companion object {
        const val PROVIDER_FRAGMENT_SELECTION = "fragment_selection"
    }
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(PROVIDER_FRAGMENT_SELECTION)
    fun provideNewFragmentSelection(): PublishSubject<String> {
        return PublishSubject.create()
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem with doing that is that I lose my event bus, which is the whole point of that module. As soon as I turn it into a class, I need to comment out the `const val ...` and my event bus no longer works.

Comment: @Alex What do you mean by event bus? If you're talking about the library you can refractor your code a bit. As far as `const val` is concerned you can move that to a `companion object` in the module class.

Comment: companion object was the final piece. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! I think I should include that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you would have had to do was add a `@JvmStatic` annotation.

```
@Module
object BusModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(PROVIDER_FRAGMENT_SELECTION)
    @JvmStatic
    fun provideNewFragmentSelection(): PublishSubject<String> {
        return PublishSubject.create()
    }
```